# Call to undefined method error

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

Get the following error.  Not sure how to fix it.  I may have things in the wrong areas as this is my first laravel project so I am not sure if I am doing it correctly.

```
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 1994:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getLewpByName()
```

Contents of EloquentLewpRepository

```
<?php namespace App\Repositories\Frontend\Lewp;

use App\Lewp;   
use App\Exceptions\GeneralException;

/**
 * Class EloquentUserRepository
 * @package App\Repositories\Lewp
 */
class EloquentLewpRepository implements LewpContract {



    /**
     * @param $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection|null|static
     * @throws GeneralException
     */
    public function findOrThrowException($id) {
        $lewp = Lewp::find($id);
        if (! is_null($lewp)) return $lewp;
        throw new GeneralException('That lewp does not exist.');
    }

    /**
     * @param $data
     * @param bool $provider
     * @return static
     */

    public function create($data) {
        $lewp = Lewp::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'title' => $data['title'],
            'text' => $data['text'],
            'sidebar' => $data['sidebar'],
            'submission_text' => $data['submission_text'],
            'type' => $data['type'],
            'content_options' => $data['content_options'],
            'link_button_text' => $data['link_button_text'],
            'text_button_text' => $data['text_button_text'],
            'options' => $data['options'],
            'comment_sort_method' => $data['comment_sort_method'],
            'hide_comment_scores' => $data['hide_comment_scores'],
            'header_mouseover-text' => $data['header_mouseover-text']
        ]);

        return $lewp;
    }

    public function searchLewpsByName($term) {
        $lewp = Lewp::where('name', 'LIKE', $term)->get();

        return $lewp;
    }

    public function getLewpByName($lewpname) {
        $lewp = Lewp::where('name', '=', $lewpname)->first();

        return $lewp;
    }

    public function getLewpId($lewpname) {
        $lewp = Lewp::select(array('id')->where('name', '=', $lewpname)->first();

        return $lewp;
    }

}
```

Contants of App/Lewp

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Lewp extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'lewps';

    /**
     * The attributes that are not mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [];

    /**
     * For soft deletes
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];   
}
```

Contents of Controller

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\Frontend;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Lewp;

/**
 * Class FrontendController
 * @package App\Http\Controllers
 */
class FrontendController extends Controller {

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('frontend.index');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function macros()
    {
        return view('frontend.macros');
    }
    public function post()
    {
        return view('frontend.post');
    }
    public function exterior()
    {
        return view('frontend.exterior');
    }
    public function submit()
    {
        return view('frontend.submit');
    }
    public function self()
    {
        return view('frontend.self');
    }
    public function lewp($name)
    {
        if(strlen($name) == 0)
        {
            return view('frontend.index');
        }
        $lewp = Lewp::getLewpByName($name);
        return view::make('frontend.lewp', array('lewp' => $lewp));
    }
}
```

Comment: Well if you are using the repository pattern why are you trying to call `getLewpByName()` on your model?

Comment: @lukasgeiter I am not positive what I am doing (I am new to the repository pattern).  I know that I need to call getLewpByName but not sure how I call it I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create method `getLewpByName` in class `EloquentLewpRepository`, but in `FrontendController` you call `Lewp::getLewpByName` with Lew is model. Do you understand problem? With this approach you should learn more about the IOC on [documents](http://laravel.com/docs/master/container).

P/s: excuse me my English.

Comment: I am not positive what you are saying (I understand that I should use the model, but not sure how I can call it then).  Can you explain how I would call it?  I am new to this approach so not positive on how it works.